# Загрузка данных со стороннего сервера

Tags: jquery, email, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать загрузку данных со стороннего сервера?

На своем сервере я не могу использовать `mail()` и cокет запросы, решил разместить на стороннем сервере файл с функцией `mail()`, как мне отправить туда данные и получить ответ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не хотите показывать людям переход на другой сервер, то вам надо пользоваться в `php curl`, хотя вряд-ли у вас эта возможность не закрыта, если закрыт простой `mail`. Кроме того имеете большую вероятность попасть в спам.

Comment: в этом-то и проблема, curl тоже закрыт, а фреймами пользоваться не хотелось бы...

Comment: не обижайтесь, но купите недорогой хостинг, повесите на сайте рекламу и он будет окупаться при посещаемости. Всеравно на бесплатном вы рекламу показываете. Понимаю, что не в тему и можно костыли типа jquery.ajax попользовать но думаю это лишнее

Comment: обижаются только девочки )) тут просто есть свои причины использовать именно этот хостинг... будем думать... )

если есть опыт использования костылей и виде ajax, буду признателен подсказке!

Comment: а делайте проще... (по крайней мере это ограничения на исходящие запросы обойдет) складывайте очередь писем в базу и каким нить спец запросом с внешнего сервера проверяйте наличие писем в очереди, ну и посылайте их... (хостеров)

Comment: попробуйте пользоватся внешним smtp к примеру гугловским. Или Отключена именно функция?

Comment: вариант с сокетами тоже не прошел...
пока делаю через иффрейм